# The strange view of radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css

Could anybody explain while it is so? And how could I make it smaller?
There is no css classes.

[image]

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioBtnList" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="id" Width="100%">
```

I guess it's too simple but... and its makes me nervous.

Comment: Your parent container is very wide and you have the width set to 100%

Answer (score 1):

This is a little confusing as you say there is no CSS and then in the tag is specifies a CSS class.
You should probably add a width to the CSS Class radioWithProperWrap to start with.
I would suggest inspecting with FireBug in Firefox as it seems to be the best way I have found to investigate CSS issues.

Comment: OOO sorry, I have pasted code earlier than delete this class from my code.
Thanks for advice!